# is it possible to change the path of toHaveScreenshot() in Playwright?

Tags: typescript, testing, playwright

The snapshot files when using toHaveScreenshot are always next to the actual test file, is it possible to change the directory of the snapshots?

method:
`await expect( page ).toHaveScreenshot( 'image.png' );`

actual path:

```
/dashboard
  /test.spec.ts-snapshots
    image.png
  test.spec.ts
```

what i want:

```
/dashboard
  /snapshots
    /test.spec.ts-snapshots
      image.png
  test.spec.ts
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set [snapShotDir](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testproject#test-project-snapshot-dir) in your playwright.config.ts file.

```
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  snapshotDir: './snapshots',
});
```